# How to display Image type from System.Drawing.Bitmap

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am reading the image from Active Directory the Property["thumbnailPhoto"].

My Model assigns it to this:

```
public Image thumbnailPhoto { get; set; }
```

My Service runs this code to put get the image from Active Directory and put it into my Model.

```
public Image GetUserPicture(string userName)
        {
            using (DirectoryEntry de = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://server.com"))
            using (DirectorySearcher ds = new DirectorySearcher(de))
            {
                ds.Filter = ("(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=User)(sAMAccountName=" + userName + "))");
                ds.PropertiesToLoad.Add("thumbnailPhoto");
                SearchResult rs = ds.FindOne();
                using (MemoryStream s = new MemoryStream(rs.Properties["thumbnailPhoto"][0] as byte[]))
                {
                    return Bitmap.FromStream(s);
                }
            }
        }
```

I call the above method and assign it to the Model from this line:

```
user.thumbnailPhoto = GetUserPicture(rs.Properties["sAMAccountName"][0].ToString());
```

This all seems to be working, no errors, I can see in the debugger that user.thumbnailPhoto is of type System.Drawing.Bitmap.

Where I am stuck now is how to display this on a webpage?

Is it possible to throw this `thumbnailPhoto` into a `Session["UserPhoto"]` since I will need it on every single page?

Comment: You will have to create helper action that returns content of the image and reference it in your model by some ID (userName?).

Comment: "Where I am stuck now is how to display this on a webpage?" - Are you displaying the image, or a string that represents the image type, like "bitmap" or "jpg"?

Comment: Well when I throw it into a Session and then replace my blank image with the session.  It just shows System.Drawing.Bitmap on the webpage. @mbeckish

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would convert it to a `Base64` `string` then use that as the source.

```
   using (MemoryStream s = new MemoryStream(rs.Properties["thumbnailPhoto"][0] as byte[]))
   {
       byte[] imageBytes = s.ToArray();
       string base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(imageBytes);
   }


   <img src="image/png;base64,@Model.ImageBase64String" />
```

Comment: I tried this but it doesn't seem to be displaying the image.  It's just a broken image box.  Here is the HTML it creates. It creates a massivly long <img> tag however.  The only difference is I am putting the image into a session variable.

Comment: The Base64 string will be very long indeed.

Comment: Yep they were Jpeg's fixed the issue.  Thanks!